# Route message to different ElasticSearchIndex using Kafka-Connect

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have a kafka topic on which multiple types of messages (all are JSON) are being published to it with header property as :- eventType = "abc" or eventType = "xyz" or eventType = "def" etc.

My requirement is to send these messages from Kafka topic to different elasticSearch index based on eventType header field being sent in kafka.
e.g. if eventType = "abc", push data to elasticsearch index = "abc123"
      if eventType = "xyz", push data to elasticsearch index = "xyz123"

I am planning to use kafka connect for this operation. I need help how can i achieve this using kafka-connect ?

I am using kafka 1.1.0 and planning to use confluentinc-kafka-connect-elasticsearch--plugin.

Here is my elastic search sink connect config file :-

```
name=elasticsearch-sink
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector
tasks.max=1
topics=test-elasticsearch-sink
topic.index.map=test-1:elastic_purchase_index1
key.ignore=true
connection.url=<url>
type.name=purchasev1
key.ignore=true
schema.ignore=true
```

Comment: Have you done research into RegexRouter? Alternatively, use ksqlDB or Kafka Streams to filter events to new topics

Comment: Regex router would be used to filter the events and apply transformation like replace the field and put into new topics. this will result putting into multiple topics from one source topic which i don't want. Kafka stream can do this i think ( consume the event and then send to corresponding elastic search index) but wanted to check if it is possible via kafka-connect ?

Comment: You wouldn't use Kafka Streams to send data to Elastic... Refer - `topic.index.map` https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-elasticsearch/configuration_options.html

Answer (score 0):

> based on eventType header field

Use [`ExtractTopic$Value`](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/transforms/extracttopic.html#examples) + [`RegexRouter`](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/transforms/regexrouter.html#id1) to route messages to individual indicies.

Then use `topics.regex` in the ElasticSearch sink to define patterns for the topics to read from

Comment: as i would be getting data from single topic only , so don't need to use topics.regex in elastic search sink connector configuration.

Comment: ExtractTopic$Value is used to extract value inside topic content, but how will it extract the header property ? My requirement is to take all messages from a single topic and map to different indices in elastic search based on header key. Can you provide the sample config in my sink config to test this? i am not able to find out how to solve it. Appreciate your help.

Comment: You need to take one topic out to multiple topic names within the Connect record (not actual Kafka topics). I don't know what your full JSON looks like, so I can't really provide an example. As I pointed out, you need to extract the value, then route it to an index (which is always based on the "topic name" metadata field of each Connect record). Therefore, update the name, you get different indices. Try a few combinations and update the question if you have issues

Comment: how would i parse kafka header field using kafka connect ? could not find in kafka connect docs. JSON of payload does not matter as routing to different indices will be based on header key irrespective of payload. i am checking what you suggested with Connect record

Comment: I think you would have to find on Github or write your own Transform to get Kafka message headers.